# Find Missing numbers in SQL query

Tags: mysql

I need to find the missing numbers between 0 and 16.

My table is like this:

```
CarId    FromCity_Id    ToCity_Id    Ran_Date    RunId
1001        0              2        01-08-2013     1
1001        5              9        02-08-2013     2
1001        11             16       03-08-2013     3
1002        0              11       02-08-2013     4
1002        11             16       08-08-2013     5
```

I need to find out:

In past three months from `now()`, between which cities the car has not ran.

For example, in the above records:

- Car 1001 not ran between 02-05 & 09-11
- Car 1002 has run fully (ie between 0-11 and 11-16)

Over all is that, I need to generate a query which shows the section between which the car has not run in past 3 months with showing the last run date.

How to make such an query please.  If any Stored Procedure please advise.

Comment: I think you need a script for this.

Comment: what does FromCity_Id and ToCity_Id mean? That the car was somewhere between those cities on that day? That the car went from and to those cities? It is just some range of cities that the car was in on that day? Seems like a bad database design.

Answer (score 2):

God help me. This uses a doubly-correlated subquery, a table that might not exist in your system, and too much caffeine. But hey, it works.

Right, here goes.

```
SELECT CarId, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT missing) missing
FROM MyTable r, 
   (SELECT @a := @a + 1 missing 
    FROM mysql.help_relation, (SELECT @a := -1) t 
    WHERE @a < 16 ) y
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT r.CarID FROM MyTable m 
    WHERE y.missing BETWEEN FromCity_Id AND ToCity_Id
       AND r.carid = m.carid)
GROUP BY CarID;
```

Produces (changing the first row for `CarID` 1002 to 0-9 to open up 10 and give us better test data):

```
+-------+---------+
| CarId | missing |
+-------+---------+
|  1001 | 3,4,10  |
|  1002 | 10      |
+-------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And how does it all work?

**Firstly**...
The inner query gives us a list of numbers from 0 to 16:

```
   (SELECT @a := @a + 1 missing 
    FROM mysql.help_relation, (SELECT @a := -1) t 
    WHERE @a < 16 ) y
```

It does that by starting at -1, and then displaying the result of adding 1 to that number for each row in some sacrificial table. I'm using `mysql.help_relation` because it's got over a thousand rows and most basic systems have it. YMMV.

**Then** we cross join that with `MyTable`:

```
SELECT CarId, ...
FROM MyTable r, 
   (...) y
```

This gives us every possible combination of rows, so we have each CarId and To/From IDs mixed with every number from 1-16.

**Filtering...**
This is where it gets interesting. We need to find rows that *don't* match the numbers, and we need to do so per `CarID`. This sort of thing would do it (as long as `y.missing` exists, which it will when we correlate the subquery):

```
    SELECT m.CarID FROM MyTable m 
    WHERE y.missing BETWEEN FromCity_Id AND ToCity_Id 
       AND m.CarID = 1001;
```

Remember: `y.missing` is set to a number between 1-16, cross-joined with the rows in `MyTable`. This gives us a list of all numbers from 1-16 where `CarID` 1001 *is* busy. We can invert that set with a `NOT EXISTS`, and while we're at it, correlate (*again*) with `CarId` so we can get all such IDs.

Then it's an easy matter of filtering the rows that don't fit:

```
SELECT CarId, ...
FROM MyTable r, 
   (...) y
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT r.CarID FROM MyTable m 
    WHERE y.missing BETWEEN FromCity_Id AND ToCity_Id 
       AND r.carid = m.carid)
```

**Output**
To give a sensible result (attempt 1), we could then get distinct combinations. Here's that version:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CarId, missing
FROM MyTable r, 
   (SELECT @a := @a + 1 missing 
    FROM mysql.help_relation, (SELECT @a := -1) t 
    WHERE @a < 16 ) y
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT r.CarID FROM MyTable m 
    WHERE y.missing BETWEEN FromCity_Id AND ToCity_Id 
       AND r.carid = m.carid);
```

This gives:

```
+-------+---------+
| CarId | missing |
+-------+---------+
|  1001 |       3 |
|  1001 |       4 |
|  1001 |      10 |
|  1002 |      10 |
+-------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

The simple addition of a `GROUP BY` and a `GROUP CONCAT` gives the pretty result you get at the top of this answer.

I apologise for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from carstable where CarId not in 
(select distinct CarId from ranRecordTable where DATEDIFF(NOW(), Ran_Date) <= 90)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idea.  Create a list of all cars and all numbers.  Then, return all combinations that are not covered by the data.  This is hard because there is more than one row for each car.

Here is one method:

```
select cars.CarId, n.n
from (select distinct CarId from t) cars cross join
     (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
      select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all
      select 8 union all select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11 union all
      select 12 union all select 13 union all select 14 union all select 15 union all
      select 16
     ) n
where t.ran_date >= now() - interval 90 day and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.ran_date >= now() - interval 90 day and
                        t2.CarId = cars.CarId and
                        n.n not between t2.FromCity_id and t2.ToCity_id
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa135/3)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`CarId` int, `FromCity_Id` int, `ToCity_Id` int, `Ran_Date` datetime, `RunId` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`CarId`, `FromCity_Id`, `ToCity_Id`, `Ran_Date`, `RunId`)
VALUES
    (1001, 0, 2, '2013-08-01 00:00:00', 1),
    (1001, 5, 9, '2013-08-02 00:00:00', 2),
    (1001, 11, 16, '2013-08-03 00:00:00', 3),
    (1002, 0, 11, '2013-08-02 00:00:00', 4),
    (1002, 11, 16, '2013-08-08 00:00:00', 5)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT r1.CarId,r1.ToCity_Id as Missing_From, r2.FromCity_Id as Missing_To,
       max(t.Ran_Date) as Last_Run_Date 
FROM (
SELECT @i1:=@i1+1 AS rownum, t.*
FROM Table1 as t, (SELECT @i1:=0) as foo
ORDER BY CarId, Ran_Date) as r1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT @i2:=@i2+1 AS rownum, t.*
FROM Table1 as t, (SELECT @i2:=0) as foo
ORDER BY CarId, Ran_Date) as r2 ON r1.CarId = r2.CarId AND 
                                   r1.ToCity_Id != r2.FromCity_Id AND
                                   r2.rownum = (r1.rownum + 1)
INNER JOIN Table1 as t ON r1.CarId = t.CarId
WHERE r1.Ran_Date >= now() - interval 90 day           
GROUP BY r1.CarId, r1.ToCity_Id, r2.FromCity_Id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa135/3/0)**:

```
| CARID | MISSING_FROM | MISSING_TO |                 LAST_RUN_DATE |
|-------|--------------|------------|-------------------------------|
|  1001 |            2 |          5 | August, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|  1001 |            9 |         11 | August, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
```